# Question about arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone explain why, `A.equals(B)` is `false`, when I initiate `B` using `int[] B = A.clone()` BUT `true` if I initiate `B` using `int[] B = A`?

```
 int[] A = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};



    int[] B = A;
    //int[] B = A.clone();

    if(A==B){//true
        System.out.println("Equal");
    }
    if(A.equals(B)){//true
        System.out.println("Equal");

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if you use

```
int[] B = A;
```

then `B` and `A` refer to the same object, so trivially they're equal. The first comparison (==) would *certainly* return false between `A` and `A.clone()` as the values refer to different objects. It sounds like arrays don't override `equals` (e.g. as `ArrayList` does), hence the clone not being equal to the original under the `equals` method either.

EDIT: Indeed, from the language specification [section 10.7, Array Members](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/arrays.html#10.7):

> All the members inherited from class Object; the only method of Object that is not inherited is its clone method.

In other words, the array overrides `clone()` but not `toString` / `hashCode` / `equals`.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, `equals` method for arrays in Java is comparing reference equality (same as `==`).

If you clone it, you have a reference different object - the clone array. But, if you just point another reference to it it's the same.

Answer (score 2):

For comparing arrays in Java, you might want to try

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(a,b);
```

If you use `a == b` they should be different- this compares their memory references.

If you use `a.equals(b)`, it probably inherits from Object, which simply uses `==`.

That probably explains why they made Arrays.equals() in the first place. Now why they chose a.equals(b) to not compare elements... hard to say.

Comment: I suppose it is the same reason as StringBuilder/StringBuffer, AtomicInteger and such do not implement equals doing "content comparison" - they usually should not be used as keys for maps, since they are made to be changed.

Comment: @Paulo +1 for mentioning why equals is what it is where it is. (That sentence is grammatically correct :-O!!)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is answered precisely by the Javadoc for clone():

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#clone%28%29

specifically:

> [ The clone() method ] Creates and
>   returns a copy of this object. The
>   precise meaning of "copy" may depend
>   on the class of the object. The
>   general intent is that, for any object
>   x, the expression:
>
> ```
>  x.clone() != x
> ```
>
> will be true, and that the expression:
>
> ```
>  x.clone().getClass() == x.getClass()
> ```
>
> will be true, but these are not
>   absolute requirements. While it is
>   typically the case that:
>
> ```
>  x.clone().equals(x)
> ```
>
> will be true, **this is not an absolute
>   requirement**.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] B = A;
```

Makes `B` point to the same object in memory as `A`, so not only are they equal, they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

when you assign B = A, you assign the reference to the same object. With clone() you get a copy of the object. The equality operator (==) tests if both symbols reference the same object where .equals method checks if the two objects have the same value (defined by the implementation of the class)